# Linux Log Monitoring using watch command

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-16.04

How to check a growing log file in Linux using watch command for every 10 seconds?
i am using ubuntu desktop, I have an growing log file. I want to check my log file every 10 seconds. how to use watch command here?

Answer (score 0):

use the following command,

Example:

watch -n 10 tail /var/log/LogFileName

watch -n 10 tail /var/log/auth.log

We can view the logs for every 10secs of a growing log file.

Comment: I think "watch -10 ls -l /path/to/file " might be more what is desired - is to check the filesize

Comment: this command is not working

Comment: watch -n 10 ls -l /path/to/file

Comment: Otherwise, what error do you get, and have you tried "man watch" to get information on the command?

Comment: Now its working fine. after adding the parameter -n it started working fine. Thanks a lot.